# How do you filter multiple related records using prisma?

Tags: javascript, prisma

Here is my sample filter, but unfortunately this doesn't work, I'm just wondering if there is a way to filter multiple related records in Prisma?

This is my sample schema:

```
model SalesReport {
  id String @id @default(uuid())
  dateCreated DateTime @default(now())
  name String
  tin String?

  // salesStaff
  salesStaff SalesStaff[]
}
```

**SOLVED:**

```
{
  skip: 0,
  orderBy: {
    name: 'desc'
  },
  where: {
    AND: [
      {
        salesStaff: {
          some: {
            AND: [
              {
                id: {
                  equals: 'fe4a3704-67a3-4a09-8471-18a95ee22bd0'
                }
              },
              {
                id: {
                  equals: 'z24a3712-67a3-4a09-8471-18a95ee22bd1'
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    ],
  },
}
```

I only need to put the `AND` inside `some` to filter multiple times on a related record (silly me)

Comment: Could you share your schema and what are you trying to achieve with the above query?

Comment: I'd like to filter an item from the related salesStaff table

Comment: Thanks Man, I've got it working—after I've inspected the generated prisma code I saw that you can add `AND` inside `some` to filter multiple times :)

Answer (score 1):

Using `AND` inside `some` helped me solve the problem, hehe.

```
{
  skip: 0,
  orderBy: {
    name: 'desc'
  },
  where: {
    AND: [
      {
        salesStaff: {
          some: {
            AND: [
              {
                id: {
                  equals: 'fe4a3704-67a3-4a09-8471-18a95ee22bd0'
                }
              },
              {
                id: {
                  equals: 'z24a3712-67a3-4a09-8471-18a95ee22bd1'
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    ],
  },
}
```